# What encoding parameters are used for the /Windows/Media sound files?

Tags: windows, audio, encoding, file-format

Specifically, what's the:

- Encoding (e.g. signed 16-bit PCM, 32-bit float, A-Law, 24-bit AWVW,
  VOX ADPCM, etc.)
- Byte order (e.g. little-endian or big-endian)
- Channel count (e.g. 1/mono, 2/stereo)
- Start offset in bytes
- Sample rate (e.g. 44100 Hz)

for the .wav files in /Windows/Media/*?

Knowing such parameters would help decode these files for advanced use.

Comment: wma is a container, not a format - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Audio and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Systems_Format

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend obtaining a tool that can read an output media info. Myself, I use `ffprobe` (part of [`FFmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org)):

```
$ ffprobe Windows\ Logon.wav
...
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
```

More detailed info:

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=pcm_s16le
codec_long_name=PCM signed 16-bit little-endian
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/22050
codec_tag_string=[1][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0001
sample_fmt=s16
sample_rate=22050
channels=2
channel_layout=unknown
bits_per_sample=16
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/22050
start_pts=N/A
start_time=N/A
duration_ts=96113
duration=4.358866
bit_rate=705600
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
[/STREAM]
```

But this is only one example file, others may differ. It would no doubt be more useful for you to get a tool to read the media info yourself; or explain what you are ultimately trying to achieve.